# Две кнопки в одной

Tags: html

В коде аудиоплеера есть две кнопки: пуск и остановка. Требуется, чтобы эти две функции работали на одной кнопке по клику. Желательно с соответствующей сменой иконки.

```
<audio id='player' src='http://retroserver.streamr.ru:8040/radio7128.mp3'/>
    <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).play()'><font size='+1'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-play'/></font></button>
    <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).pause()'><font size='+1'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-stop'/></font></button>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).volume+=0.1'><font size='+2'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-volume-up'/></font></button>
    <button onclick='document.getElementById(&quot;player&quot;).volume=Math.max(document.getElementById(&quot;player&quot;).volume - 0.1, 0)'><font size='+2'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-volume-down'/></font></button>
```

Comment: А вызывать при нажатии на какую кнопку?

Comment: При нажатии проверять процесс воспроизведения. Если активен, то останавливать, если нет, то начинать. Туда же вставить смену иконки.